# Are the following maps linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

A linear map $T:V\rightarrow W$ is a function satisfying:

1. $T(v_1+v_2)=T(v_1)+T(v_2), \forall v_1,v_2\in V$
2. $T(\alpha\cdot v_1)=\alpha\cdot T(v_1), \forall \alpha \in \mathbb F$

I am unsure if I correctly applied these properties to polynomials over a field. Could someone please verify whether my procedure is correct? Thank you.

Notation: $\mathbb R [t]_n$ denotes the field of polynomials of degree $\leq n$.

(a) $T: \mathbb R [t]_2 \rightarrow \mathbb R [t]_3, T(f(t))=t^2+f(t)$

Let $v_1=f(t), v_2=g(t) \in \mathbb R [t]_2$. Then, we try to establish both conditions.

1. $T(f(t)+g(t))=t^2+f(t)+g(t)=T(v_1)+g(t)$

Thus, our first condition fails,  and so, (a) is not a linear map.

(b) $T: \mathbb R [t]_2 \rightarrow \mathbb R [t]_3, T(f(t))=tf(t)+t^2f'(t)$

Let $v_1=f(t), v_2=g(t) \in \mathbb R [t]_2$. Then, we try to establish both conditions.

1. $T(f(t)+g(t))=t(f(t)+g(t))+t^2(f'(t)+g'(t))=tf(t)+tg(t)+t^2f'(t)+t^2g'(t)=(tf(t)+t^2f'(t))+(tg(t)+t^2g'(t))=T(v_1)+T(v_2)$
2. $T(\alpha f(t))=\alpha tf(t)+\alpha t^2f'(t)=\alpha (tf(t)+t^2f'(t))=\alpha T(v_1)$

Since (b) fulfills both conditions, it is a linear map.

My confusion primarily arises from the first derivative function in (b). Is there any particular process that I have neglected, or is my solution fine?

Comment: Looks good! Notice the derivative is a linear map (over $\mathbb R$).

Comment: This looks fine. For a), you could also note that a linear map necessarily maps the zero vector to the zero vector, so the map can't be linear. Also, you're not working with polynomial fields, but rather polynomials over a field.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. Made the correction above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your working is fine. Note however that $\mathbb{R}[t]_n$ is a vector space, not a field.